# Magento 2.3.1 Download an excel file with PHPSpreadsheet

Tags: magento2, controllers, factory, file, download

Trying to create a download button for an Xlsx file. Using PHPSpreadsheet for this however when downloading the file it seems corrupted with a stack trace at the bottom of excel files:

```
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'Cannot modify h...', '/var/www/buzzma...', 148, Array)
#1 /var/www/mage2/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php(148): setcookie('X-Magento-Vary', 'b5a9446b2918d35...', 1553779873, '/', '', true, true)
#2 /var/www/mage2/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php(101): Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager->setCookie('X-Magento-Vary', 'b5a9446b2918d35...', Array)
#3 /var/www/mage2/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Response/Http.php(108): Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager->setSensitiveCookie('X-Magento-Vary', 'b5a9446b2918d35...', Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\SensitiveCookieMetadata))
#4 /var/www/mage2/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http->sendVary()
#5 /var/www/mage2/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/Response/HttpPlugin.php(25): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->sendVary()
#6 /var/www/mage2/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\Response\HttpPlugin->beforeSendResponse(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#7 /var/www/mage2/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#8 /var/www/mage2/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/Interceptor.php(117): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendResponse', Array, Array)
#9 /var/www/mage2/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(186): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->sendResponse()
#10 /var/www/mage2/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(157): Magento\Framework\App\Http->handleDeveloperMode(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Exception))
#11 /var/www/mage2/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Http->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Exception))
#12 /var/www/mage2/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->___callParent('catchException', Array)
#13 /var/www/mage2/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Exception))
#14 /var/www/mage2/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('catchException', Array, Array)
#15 /var/www/mage2/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Exception))
#16 /var/www/mage2/public_html/pub/index.php(40): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#17 {main}
```

Exiting with exit; after `$objWriter->save("php://output");` seems to work fine but seems messy.

This is an example of my code within my controller:

```
public function buildXls($list) {
    $fileName = $this->getFileName($list) . ".xlsx";
    $rootPath = $this->directoryList->getRoot();

    $objPHPExcel = new spreadsheet;
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A1', "TEST");

    /*Original Method*/
    /*
    $objWriter = io_factory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Xlsx');
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $fileName);
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
    $objWriter->save("php://output");
    //FIX
   exit;        
   */
    /*Magento Method?*/
    $fileDirectory = \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA;

    $filePath =  $this->directoryList->getPath($fileDirectory) . "/" . $fileName;
    $objWriter = io_factory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Xlsx');
    $objWriter->save($filePath);

    $resultRaw = $this->fileFactory->create(
        $fileName,
        @file_get_contents($filePath)
    );

    return $resultRaw;
    /*Magento Method End*/
}
```

Using the Magento method or original method used without exiting however all show as corrupt I believe because that stack trace that shows within files. How can I download this file that has been generated properly preferably the "Magento way"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tadaa:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

public function __construct(
    FileFactory $_fileFactory,
    DateTime $dateTime
) {
    $this->_fileFactory = $_fileFactory;
    $this->dateTime = $dateTime;
}


return $this->_fileFactory->create(
        sprintf('myreport%s.xlsx', $this->dateTime->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s')), //file name during download
        [
            'type' => 'filename',
            'value' => 'spreadsheet_export/spreadsheets/' . $localName, //relative path to your locally saved spreadsheet with  $writer->save($fullpath);
            'rm' => true  // can delete file after use
        ],
        DirectoryList::MEDIA,
        'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    );
```

Check out

```
vendor/magento/module-offline-shipping/Controller/Adminhtml/System/Config/ExportTablerates.php
vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Pdfinvoices.php
```

I have taken this out from a much larger class so add all the necessary controller paraphernalia obviously